# Node.js: share connection object throughout the application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a having issues with implementing `generic-pool` using puppeteer. Below is my relevant part of the code.

***UPDATE***

Thanks @Jacob for the help and i am more clear about the concept and how it works and the code is also more readable and clear. I am still having issues where a generic pool is getting created on every request. How do i ensure that the same generic pool is used every time instead of creating new one

**browser-pool.js**

```
const genericPool = require('generic-pool');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

class BrowserPool {
  static async getPool() {
    const browserParams = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? {
      headless: false,
      devtools: false,
      executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
     }
     :
     {
       headless: true,
       devtools: false,
       executablePath: 'google-chrome-unstable',
       args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']
     };

    const factory = {
      create: function() {
        return puppeteer.launch(browserParams);
      },
      destroy: function(instance) {
        console.log('closing browser in hrere.....');
        instance.close();
      }
    };

    const opts = {
      max: 5
    };

    this.myBrowserPool = genericPool.createPool(factory, opts);
  }

  static async returnPool() {
    if (this.myBrowserPool == "") {
      getPool();
    }

    return this.myBrowserPool.acquire();
  }
}

BrowserPool.myBrowserPool = null;
module.exports =  BrowserPool;
```

**process-export.js**

```
const BrowserPool = require('./browser-pool');
async function performExport(params){
  const myPool = BrowserPool.getPool();
  const resp = BrowserPool.myBrowserPool.acquire().then(async function(client){
    try {
      const url = config.get('url');
      const page = await client.newPage();

      await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: ['networkidle2', 'domcontentloaded']});
      let gotoUrl = `${url}/dashboards/${exportParams.dashboardId}?csv_export_id=${exportParams.csvExportId}`;
//more processing
      await page.goto(gotoUrl, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
      await myPool().myBrowserPool.release(client);
      return Data;
    } catch(err) {
      try {
        const l = await BrowserPool.myBrowserPool.destroy(client);
      } catch(e) {
      }
      return err;
    }
  }).catch(function(err) {
    return err;
  });
  return resp;
}

module.exports.performExport = performExport;
```

My understanding is that

1) When the application starts I can spin up for example `2 chromium` instances and then when ever i want to visit a page i can use either of the two connections, so the browsers are essentially open and we improve the performance since the browser start can take time. is this correct?

2) Where do I place the `acquire()` code, I understand this should be in the `app.js`, so we acquire the instances rite when the app boots, but my pupeteer code is in a different file, how do i pass the browser reference in the file which has my  pupeteer code.

When I use the above the code, a new browser instances spins up every time and the `max` property is not considered and it opens up as many instances are requested.

My apologies if its something very trial and i might have not understood the concept fully. Any help in clarifying this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a pool, you'll need to use `.acquire()` to obtain an object, and then `.release()` when you're done so the object is returned to the pool and made available to something else. Without using `.release()`, you'd might as well have no pool at all. I like to use this helper pattern with pools:

```
class BrowserPool {
  // ...

  static async withBrowser(fn) {
    const pool = BrowserPool.myBrowserPool;
    const browser = await pool.acquire();
    try {
      await fn(browser);
    } finally {
      pool.release(browser);
    }
  }
}
```

This can be used like this anywhere in your code:

```
await BrowserPool.withBrowser(async browser => {
  await browser.doSomeThing();
  await browser.doSomeThingElse();
});
```

The key is the `finally` clause makes sure that whether your tasks complete or throw an error, you'll cleanly release the browser back to the pool every time.

It sounds like you might have the concept of the `max` option backwards as well and are expecting the browser instances to be spawned up to `max`. Rather, `max` means "only create up to `max` number of resources." If you try to acquire a sixth resource without anything having been released, for example, the `acquire(...)` call will block until one item is returned to the pool.

The `min` option, on the other hand, means "keep at least this many items on hand at all times", which you can use to pre-allocate resources. If you want 5 items to be created in advance, set `min` to 5. If you want 5 items and only five items to be created, set both `min` and `max` to 5.

**Update**:

I notice in your original code that you destroy in case of error and release when there isn't an error. Still would prefer the benefit of a wrapper function like mine to centralize all resource acquiring/releasing logic (the SRP approach). Here's how it could be updated to automatically destroy on errors instead:

```
class BrowserPool {
  // ...

  static async withBrowser(fn) {
    const pool = BrowserPool.myBrowserPool;
    const browser = await pool.acquire();
    try {
      await fn(browser);
      pool.release(browser);
    } catch (err) {
      await pool.destroy(browser);
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

**Addendum**

Figuring out what's going on in your code will be easier if you embrace the async function instead of mixing async function stuff and Promise callback stuff. Here's how it can be rewritten:

```
async function performExport(params){
  const myPool = BrowserPool.myBrowserPool;
  const client = await myPool.acquire();

  try {
    const url = config.get('url');
    const page = await client.newPage();

    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: ['networkidle2', 'domcontentloaded']});
    let gotoUrl = `${url}/dashboards/${exportParams.dashboardId}?csv_export_id=${exportParams.csvExportId}`;
//more processing
    await page.goto(gotoUrl, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    await myPool.release(client);
    return Data;
  } catch(err) {
    try {
      const l = await myPool.destroy(client);
    } catch(e) {
    }
    return err; // Are you sure you want to do this? Would suggest throw err.
  }
}
```

Comment: many thanks for the answer, i have been strugling to understand this fully and this reply helps. I am also trying to understand that when my app boots up, should i be seeing chrom instances spin up already? or will the instance spin up only when acquire is called? in that case how is this different from not using in pool

Comment: I believe it spins them up lazily when acquire is called. The main difference with using a pool is you can cap the number of instances you are creating and reuse them when you're done with them, reducing memory usage and only absorbing slow object creation costs once.

Comment: If you want them to be created in advance, you could try the `min` option.

Comment: thanks @Jacob and sorry for the follow up questions, in your solution, you have added `withBrowser ` function in the same `BrowserPool` class, in my current flow, i see that release does not get called but i need to explicitly call destroy, is it because i do not call acquire and release in the same class like you have?

Comment: What do you mean release is not called; are you calling release in a finally clause like in my code, in an async function? It should always get called after the promise resolves/rejects.

Comment: `destroy` is something different. `release` returns the item to the pool so code later on can use the same object. `destroy` is for if you never want to use that object again.

Comment: If you have pool acquire/release code in multiple places I'd encourage you to change that, because then it's hard to put together a clean mental picture of how resources are being maintained. The benefit of the pattern I showed is you have all browser resource management centralized in one place.

Comment: thanks @Jacob, thanks for your explanation, I am getting to understand this more better now. I have just updated my question, with how i call acquire and release. Is it because i call release in the then of acquire that its not getting called? Should i be calling after `then` block?

Comment: Your code isn't super clear to me. It looks like you're not using the same pool object in all cases. Sometimes you're using `BrowserPool.myBrowserPool` and sometimes you're using `myPool().myBrowserPool`. I'd use `BrowserPool.myBrowserPool` in _all_ cases, unless I'm misunderstanding your code.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob, i will use `BrowserPool.myBrowserPool`, I have tried this, but release does not seem be getting called. It's only when i call destroy the browser gets closed.The `console.log` you see in the destory function does not get called when i do a `release`, but if i explicitly call `destroy`  it works

Comment: Still not clear on what you mean by "not getting called." As in the line of code where you're calling release isn't being hit, or it _is_ getting called and something unexpected is happening? If it's the former, then whether it gets called or not is dependent on your code before it, right? Is an error being thrown and you're hitting your `catch` callback instead?

Comment: Flattening your code into just an async function that uses await/try/catch instead of using Promise callbacks will make your code flow clearer.

Comment: thanks @Jacob, this makes more sense now. I had one more question, i was expecting `.release()` to call whatever i have written in `destroy` in my `const factory`, is that correct? or release keeps the browser open for other requests? thanks

Comment: `pool.destroy(...)` calls destroy. `release` is if you _don't_ want to destroy. The idea is that later code that acquires gets the exact same browser as it was before it was released so you don't have to create a new one.

Comment: hi @Jacob, i tried your approach with `withBrowser(fn)`, but the max property is still not considered, it looks the a new generic pool gets created when i call `await BrowserPool.withBrowser(async browser => {`. How do i ensure that the same pool is refered always. It might also be usefull to know that i am using the browser pool in background job using `bull`

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by background jobs, but if these are running in separate processes, you'll be unable to share a pool. Two JavaScript processes or even worker threads cannot share any objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214430/discussion-between-opensource-developer-and-jacob).

Comment: hi @Jacob, do you want to update the answer based on our chat, i can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Will just leave a comment here. The pool was working fine. However, the code was not running any requests concurrently, and it was also running requests in their own child processes, so they could not share a browser pool. Solution was to not use pooling and to use the concurrency controls of the worker queue library instead.